# Error en consola: fatal error: unixodbc.h: No such file or directory al intentar instalar sqlsrv y pdo_sqlsrv drivers para PHP 7.4 en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

Primero les muestro el error que tengo a nivel de consola:

```
/usr/include/sqltypes.h:56:10: fatal error: unixodbc.h: No such file or directory 56  
| #include "unixodbc.h"
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:192: conn.lo] Error 1
ERROR: 'make' failed
```

Necesito levantar una aplicación web que corra en ***Linux Ubuntu 20.04***, con ***Apache***, ***PHP 7.4*** o superior y ***SQLServer***.
Tengo varios días intentando instalar los drivers para poder conectarme a un ***SQL Server 2017 Standard*** desde ***PHP***.
He instalado ***XAMPP 8.0.25*** y ***XAMPP 7.3.20*** y he recibido el mismo error. También he intentado instalar los paquetes de forma independiente y de igual manera siempre aparece el mismo error.
He seguido la guía oficial de Microsoft:
[aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver#installing-on-ubuntu/) y [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnC_uOahq7U), pero cuando llega el momento de correr el comando:

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

salta el error.

Todo este esfuerzo lo vengo haciendo en una máquina virtual con Ubuntu 20.04 de la cual tengo una copia original cuando recién la instalé.
Han habido momentos donde he probado tantas diferentes posibilidades que decido apagar la VM y volver a trabajar en una copia limpia y libre de paquetes quizá innecesarios, pero no logro dar con el problema.
En el video que les adjunte acá arriba, a la persona que lo hizo, también le aparecieron algunos errores en el camino, pero rápidamente los logró resolver, pero en mi caso ese error en particular no me deja avanzar.

Comment: Buen día señores. Ya logré dar con la solución. La vi en Youtube, en el canal de Peter Schneider: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-bCb36zP_s  favor mirar el minuto 2:17. Ahí vemos la siguiente instrucción: apt-get install unixodbc-dev=2.3.7 unixodbc=2.3.7 odbcinst1debian2=2.3.7 odbcinst=2.3.7

Comment: El asunto fue tratado ampliamente [aquí](https://github.com/microsoft/linux-package-repositories/issues/36). El problema es que ciertas versiones no se instalan por defecto los archivos de `unixodbc` y debes hacerlo manualmente, no hay más misterio.